# Javascript + namespacing + FF issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, namespaces

```
var utils = function() {
    function getMyPrivateName() {
        return "Caoimhin";
    }
    return {
        messages: {
            getMyPublicName: function getMyPublicName() {
                return "Kevin";
            },
            sayHello: function() {
                document.writeln("hello " + getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
                document.writeln("hello " + getMyPrivateName() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
    };
} ();

utils.messages.sayHello();
```

I am playing around with javascript namespaces and have encountered unexpected behaviour. I develop mostly in IE as that is the target browser for our intranet application.

In IE the above, when included on a blank page, outputs:

> hello Kevin
>   hello Caoimhin

In FF the script encounters an error:

> getMyPublicName is not defined

If I comment out the offending line:

```
//document.writeln("hello " + getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
```

FF outputs:

> hello Caoimhin

So I know it can access the private function...

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And what I need to do in order to have a cross browser solution similar to the above..

I know I could write something like:

```
document.writeln("hello " + utils.messages.getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
```

but would prefer not to....

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have stumbled across a bug in the JScript language as used by IE.

```
getMyPublicName: function getMyPublicName() {
    ...
},
```

The `function getMyPublicName()` value here is an inline function expression that has been given an optional identifier `getMyPublicName` that is the same as its property name in the owner. (`sayHello` omits this identifier.)

What the optional identifier *should* do according to the ECMAScript standard is make a reference to the function visible in the scope of the function body itself, under the identifier name `getMyPublicName`. This could be used for making an anonymous inline function that referred to itself (for recursion).

What it *actually* does in IE, incorrectly, is make the function visible under the name `getMyPublicName` in the parent scope (the `utils` function). Because it's visible in that scope it becomes visible to  the child scope of the `sayHello` function too, making your code work when it shouldn't, really.

You can use `this.` to get the reference to `getMyPublicName` properly, as suggested by Dustin. Alternatively if you want to avoid the issues of `this`-binding in JavaScript (eg. because you're going to pass the `sayHello` function as a delegate to a timeout or event), you might prefer to put the public functions in parent scope too:

```
var utils = function() {
    function getMyPrivateName() {
        return "Caoimhin";
    }
    function getMyPublicName() {
        return "Kevin";
    }
    function sayHello() {
        document.writeln("hello " + getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
        document.writeln("hello " + getMyPrivateName() + "<br/>");
    }
    return {
        messages: {
            getMyPublicName: getMyPublicName,
            sayHello: sayHello,
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, some great information here for me.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox' behaviour is conforming, as a function definition within an object initialiser is a **function expression** and *not* a **function declaration**.

ECMA-262, 3rd edition, section 13:

> The Identifier in a FunctionExpression
>   can be referenced from inside the
>   FunctionExpression's FunctionBody to
>   allow the function to call itself
>   recursively. However, unlike in a
>   FunctionDeclaration, the Identifier in
>   a FunctionExpression cannot be
>   referenced from and does not affect
>   the scope enclosing the
>   FunctionExpression.

I suggest moving the definition out of the object initialiser:

```
var utils = (function() {
    function getMyPrivateName() {
        return "Caoimhin";
    }
    function getMyPublicName() {
        return "Kevin";
    }
    return {
        messages: {
            getMyPublicName: getMyPublicName,
            sayHello: function() {
                document.writeln("hello " + getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
                document.writeln("hello " + getMyPrivateName() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
    };
})();


utils.messages.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of scope:

```
var utils = function() {
    function getMyPrivateName() {
        return "Caoimhin";
    }
    return {
        messages: {
            getMyPublicName: function() {
                return "Kevin";
            },
            sayHello: function() {
                document.writeln("hello " + this.getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
                document.writeln("hello " + getMyPrivateName() + "<br/>");
            }
        }
    };
} ();

utils.messages.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is:

```
var utils = function() {
    var getMyPrivateName = function () {
        return "Caoimhin";
    };

    var self = {
        getMyPublicName: function () {
            return "Kevin";
        },
        sayHello: function() {
            document.writeln("hello " + getMyPublicName() + "<br/>");
            document.writeln("hello " + self.getMyPrivateName() + "<br/>");
        };

    return self;
}();
```